# Excel file receive same Content but different Header Field

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, openpyxl

My customer send me a data materialsheet.xlsx which had N rows and N no of Columns but in specific i needed only 12 Cols only.

1st time he sent a Materialsheet.xlsx

| material | Long Des | Ref |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11000021 | Panda toy | Cotton Toy |
| 11100212 | Red Panda Toy | Plastic Toy |

2nd time he sent a Materialsheet.xlsx

| Internal | Describe | Location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11000021 | Panda toy | Cotton Toy |
| 11100212 | Red Panda Toy | Plastic Toy |

my code:

```
   ds1 = pd.read_excel('Materialsheet.xlsx', usecols=['Material', 'Group', 'Priority', 'Long Des', 'Ref', 'Qty','Shape'],index_col=False) 

   ds1 = ds1[['Material', 'Group','Priority','Long Des','Qty','Shape','Ref']]

   print(ds1)
```

or

```
    ds = pd.read_excel('Materialsheet.xlsx', usecols=['Internal', 'Alter.Group', 'Priority', 'Describe', 'Location', 'Qty','image'],index_col=False)
```

`
i always change my excel header or code line to get the output

i need a code for for this kindly of header field i header field name change.

1. if Column name "A"(material) change to "C"(PN)
2. if Column name "B"(Internal) change to "C"(PN)

is this possible need support.

Answer (score 0):

Just use .rename() method:

```
ds1.rename(columns={'material': 'PN'} inplace=True)
ds.rename(columns={'Internal': 'PN'}, inpalce=True)
```

You can also write custom function, to always change column name, despite which file you're using:

```
def rename_column(df):
    columns_list = list(df.column)
    if 'material' in column_list:
        df.rename(columns={'material': 'PN'}, inplace=True)
    elif 'Internal' in column_list:
        df.rename(columns={'Internal': 'PN'}, inplace=True)
    return df
```

Comment: i don't know how it works.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77540775/22825651

Answer (score 0):

```
below my code:

os.getcwd()

Chd= os.chdir('D:/NX_BACKWORK/Output/BOM')
Chd = os.getcwd()

ds1 = pd.read_excel('BOM.xlsx',index_col=False) 

column_list = ds1.head()
for col in column_list:
    print(col)

def rename_column(ds1):
    columns_list = list(ds1.col)
    if 'Material' in column_list:
        ds1.rename(columns={'Material': 'PartNumber'}, inplace=True)
    elif 'Internal' in column_list:
        ds1.rename(columns={'Internal': 'PartNumber'}, inplace=True)
    return ds1


ds1 = pd.read_excel('BOM.xlsx', usecols=['PartNumber', 'Group', 'Priority', 'Long Des', 'RefList', 'Qty','Shape'],index_col=False) 



ds1 = ds1[['PartNumber', 'Group','Priority','Long Des','Qty','Shape','RefList']]
ds1['RefList'] = ds1['RefList'].str.replace("_x000D_","")
ds1['RefList'] = ds1['RefList'].str.replace(" ","")
ds1['RefList'] = ds1['RefList'].str.replace("\n","")
print(ds1)

#ds1 = pd.read_excel('Filename_OP.xlsx','BOM', index_col=False)

ds2 = ds1.explode('RefList')

ds2['RefList'] = ds2['RefList'].str.replace(" "," ")

#ds2.drop(ds2.iloc[:, 1:6], inplace=True, axis=1)

print(ds2)

ds2.rename(columns = {'PartNumber':'B_Part_No'}, inplace = True)

ds2.rename(columns = {'RefList':'B_Ref_List'}, inplace = True)

ds2['B_Ref_List'] = ds2['B_Ref_List'] .str.strip('[]').str.split(',')

ds2.to_dict()

ds2.explode ('B_Ref_List',ignore_index=True)

ds3 = ds2.explode('B_Ref_List',ignore_index=True)

ds2 = ds2[['Group','Priority','B_Part_No']]

ds3.head()

T10_col = ds3.pop('B_Ref_List') # col-1

ds3.insert(0, 'B_Ref_List', T10_col)

ds3 = ds3[['B_Ref_List','B_Part_No']]

ds1.dropna(subset=['RefList'], inplace=True)
ds3.dropna(subset=['B_Ref_List'], inplace=True)

with pd.ExcelWriter("D:/NX_BACKWORK/Output/Verified/BOM_List_OP.xlsx") as writer:

        ds1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="BOM", index=False)
        ds2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="BOM1", index=False)
        ds3.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="BOM2", index=False)
```